# Get value in Json with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have an API that returns JSON like this:

```js
[{
    "Code": "001",
    "Name": "xyz",
    "Members": [{
        "FullName": "User1"
    }]
}, {
    "Code": "002",
    "Name": "asd",
    "Members": [{
        "FullName": "User2"
    }]
}]
```

I want to replace Name and member in my label matching with "Code" and i want to do that with ajax. How can achieve the matching with Code?

This is my implementation:

```js
$('#btnFind').on('click', function () {
    var Code = $("#input_edit_code").val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/mvc/ComplaintHandlerSquadGetListPage",
        success: function () {
            alert();
        },
        error: function (ex) {
            alert(ex.title);
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: I cannot fathom what you are asking for here.

Comment: Do you mean, you want to edit the Name and Member property for elements with a specific Code value?

Comment: I want to get name matching with entered code eg: if user enter  $("#input_edit_code").val() = 001 get name "xyz"

Comment: @JohnConnor Are you trying to create some sort of auto-complete search box?

Comment: No , i already did auto-complete.I just want to when user enter the Code number like "001" press button and shown its name .

Comment: You should really try to write some code by yourself before asking questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use javascript's filter and map Array's functions.

Let's pretend you store the code typed by the user inside this codeNumber var

```
var codeNumber = '002';
```

Your array of members:

```
var members = [{"Code":"001","Name":"xyz","Members":[{"FullName":"User1"}]},{"Code":"002","Name":"asd","Members":[{"FullName":"User2"}]}];
```

A function to filter your array by Code :

```
var byCode = function(member) {
  return member.Code === codeNumber;
};
```

A function to get the name of the filtered member :

```
var getName = function(member) {
  return member.Name;
};
```

You get the member's name

```
var memberName = members.filter(byCode).map(getName).toString();

console.log(memberName);
```

Comment: Thank you for help that works

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe AJAX and simple JSON alone can do what you want.

JSON is a way to structure objects - JavaScript Object Notation. It only structures data.

AJAX is an Asynchronous means of making an HttpRequest. It asks a server for something.

If you use AJAX to ask for a JSON file. You will get the JSON data.

I believe you have two options:

1. Use AJAX to request the data from the server. The server will then have to load the JSON file, find the correct data and return the correct data to AJAX.
2. Use AJAX to get the JSON data. Find the correct data with JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the success handler, you can compare something like this:

```
success: function(response) {
    // yourObject that matches the code 
    var yourObject = response.filter(function(item) {
       return item.Code === Code
    });
    // wherever you want to show this name
    $("body").text(yourObject.Name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
       type: "get",
       url: "/mvc/ComplaintHandlerSquadGetListPage",
       success: function (result) {
           jQuery(result).each(function(i, item){
           if(item.Code == Code)
           {
               $('#myid').text(item.Name);
           }
       },
       error: function (ex) {
           alert(ex.title);
       }
});
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your code so others understand better what this does.